# How can I move a div from top to bottom on mobile layouts?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4, but if it works on version 3, it should work on v4.

I have 2 divs within a column like so:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div>TOP ON DESKTOP, BOTTOM ON MOBILE</div>
        <div>BOTTOM ON DESKTOP, TOP ON MOBILE</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way I can get the divs to swap around on a mobile device? I do not want to use any JavaScript here; I would like to use Bootstrap classes only, if possible.

If it is not possible with Bootstrap, then CSS-only please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171408/how-do-i-change-bootstrap-3-column-order-on-mobile-layout

Comment: That applies to sorting columns, i need to sort 2 rows

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This can be achieved using CSS' `flexbox`.

- Add a new selector `.col-xs-12` with the following properties:

  - `display: flex;` tells the children to use the `flexbox` model
  - `flex-direction: column-reverse;` will ensure that the children flow from bottom to top (instead of the default left to right)

Run the below Snippet in full screen and resize the window to see the order of the elements change.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .col-xs-12 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div>TOP ON DESKTOP, BOTTOM ON MOBILE</div>
    <div>BOTTOM ON DESKTOP, TOP ON MOBILE</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## A Bootstrap method

This can also be achieved using Bootstrap:

- Add the following classes to the container:

  - `d-flex` to make the container use flexbox
  - `flex-column-reverse` to order the children in reverse order on small screens
  - `flex-sm-column` to order the children in normal order on larger screens

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 d-flex flex-column-reverse flex-sm-column">
    <div>TOP ON DESKTOP, BOTTOM ON MOBILE</div>
    <div>BOTTOM ON DESKTOP, TOP ON MOBILE</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you save me bro nice

Answer (score 6):

The following code works for me:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .xs-column-reverse {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 xs-column-reverse">
    <div>TOP ON DESKTOP, BOTTOM ON MOBILE</div>
    <div>BOTTOM ON DESKTOP, TOP ON MOBILE</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.col-xs-12 { height: 200px; position:relative; }
.col-xs-12 div { position:absolute; top:0; left: 0; width:100%; }
.col-xs-12 div:last-child { top: auto; bottom: 0; }

@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .col-xs-12 div { top:auto; bottom:0; }
    .col-xs-12 div:last-child { top: 0; bottom: auto; }
}
```