# How do I change Bootstrap column order on mobile layout?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a layout for desktop
[1][2][3]

But I want this when on mobile device like
[2][3][1]

is it possible? I am using bootstrap 3.

Comment: check if the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171408/how-do-i-change-bootstrap-3-column-order-on-mobile-layout) solves your problem

Comment: Yes, I checked this. But there is 2 column and I have 3 column...

Answer (score 0):

Check this

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-4 col-xs-4">2</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-4 col-xs-4">3</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-8 col-xs-4">1</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Fiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/c9sg224y/5/)