# How to change the vertical order of Bootstrap grid

Tags: css, grid

My actual layout looks like this:

A B 
A B 
A B 
A 
A 
..

A Elements are in a div.col-sm-7.col-sm-pull-5
and B Elements are in div.col-sm-5.col-sm-push-7

on mobile it looks like this:

B 
B 
B 
A 
A 
A 
..

Now I want to enter a element C after the B elements:

A B 
A B 
A B 
A C 
A 
..

on regular displays and on mobile it should look like this:

B 
B 
B 
A 
A 
A 
.. 
C

Does anybody have a good solution?

Comment: May be this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171408/how-do-i-change-bootstrap-3-column-order-on-mobile-layout

Answer (score 0):

Hey i think what you are trying to achieve can be done with push and pull :

"Easily change the order of our built-in grid columns with .col-md-push-* and .col-md-pull-* modifier classes."

This is from bootstrap doc.