# Bootstrap grid collapse -> right columns on top?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've read that I can order my grid columns using https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering, however, unfortunately, I cannot find a way to have "right column first" only in collapsed state.

Currently I have two columns "LEFT" (col-lg-4) and "RIGHT" (col-lg-8). I want the RIGHT column to collapse on top of the LEFT column, but stay on the right side if not collapsed.

How to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `float: right` to both and place the right one before the left one in the HTML code.

Comment: This sounds like a hackaround, is this really "the way to go"?

Comment: You can also add the class `.pull-right` instead - that contains the `float: right` property and brings the same result. Still you'll have to reverse the elements in the HTML, as i wrote.

Answer (score 3):

For more recent Bootsrap versions you can use flex-column reverse and set the size at which reverse property happens (i.e. below flex-lg-row):

```
<div class="row flex-column-reverse flex-lg-row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        sidebar
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        main
    </div>
</div>
```

There is a duplicate thread at:
[How do I change Bootstrap 3 column order on mobile layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171408/how-do-i-change-bootstrap-3-column-order-on-mobile-layout)

Answer (score 1):

u can use order, set the first col with higher order (like 'order-md-3'), form md to high size window it will on right side because higher order, and the second col will on left because its not have order its same 0 order (the lower order will on left).

```
<div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-5 order-md-3">
        <img src="../img/profile/fotocv.png" alt="foto profile" width="100%">
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="plang">
          <h1>Hi!</h1>
          <h1>I'M AMMARIDHO SIREGAR</h1>
          <h3>Web Developer</h3>
        </div>
      </div>

 </div>
```