# Bootstrap column order on mobile?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two sections. When mobile, the second div goes under first div. But how can I get the second div first when mobile (col-sm or col-xs)?

```
<div class="col-md-8">
Hello
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
world
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change Bootstrap 3 column order on mobile layout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171408/how-do-i-change-bootstrap-3-column-order-on-mobile-layout)

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering

Comment: How can I do it without using bootstrap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Use boostrap class `col-lg-push-x` and `col-lg-pull-x`.

Also see Demo Here: [enter link description here](http://s.codepen.io/sevilayha/debug/ihgLz)

**Exp:**

```
<div class='row'>
<div class='col-lg-5 col-lg-push-5'>World</div>
<div class='col-lg-5 col-lg-pull-5'>Hello</div>
<div class='col-lg-2'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to:

```
<div class="col-lg-9 col-lg-push-3">
Hello
</div>

<div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-pull-9">
World!
</div>
```