# Bootstrap 3.0 : plot left div on bottom in mobile view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

i have 2 divs  like this

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><img src="..."></div>
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">Content about image goes here </div>
</div>
```

Now on mobile image comes on top and then comes the content , i want image to come after the content in responsive mode , How it can be done .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change Bootstrap 3 column order on mobile layout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171408/how-do-i-change-bootstrap-3-column-order-on-mobile-layout)

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-push-6">Content about image goes here </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-pull-6"><img src="..."></div>
</div>
```