# Bootstrap column stacking on mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to get the col-md-6 to stack below the col-md-4 on mobile but cant get it to work. Any advice how to achieve this would be great.

```
<footer>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-12">
      <?php
          wp_nav_menu( array(
              'menu'              => 'footer',
              'theme_location'    => 'footer',
              'depth'             => 1,
              'container'         => 'div',
              'container_id'      => 'footer-nav',
              'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
              'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
              'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
          );
      ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 copyright-text">
      <p>Copyright © <?php echo date("Y"); ?> Elliott Davidson. All Rights Reserved.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: See this similar answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171408/how-do-i-change-bootstrap-3-column-order-on-mobile-layout

Comment: I managed to find a solution by adding a class to the col-md-6 and floating it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look into using `order` property from utilizing `flexbox`. Check out the documentation [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/order/).

What you'd do is something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row flex">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-12 first">Div 1</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 copyright-text second">Div2</div>
  </div>
</div>


/* Make sure to use all the proper prefixers */
/* Allow this to be up to mobile of 767px */
@media all and ( max-width: 767px ) {
    .flex { display: flex; }
    .first { order: 2; }
    .second { order: 1; }
}
```

[Take a look at this codepen](https://codepen.io/ishio/pen/bWOeXX) which will have a solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Switch the order of the columns (mobile first) and then use [Bootstrap's column ordering](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-6 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-12 copyright-text">
      <p>Copyright © <?php echo date("Y"); ?> Elliott Davidson. All Rights Reserved.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-4 col-xs-12">
      <?php
          wp_nav_menu( array(
              'menu'              => 'footer',
              'theme_location'    => 'footer',
              'depth'             => 1,
              'container'         => 'div',
              'container_id'      => 'footer-nav',
              'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
              'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
              'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
          );
      ?>
    </div>    
</div>
```

[Bootply example](https://www.bootply.com/CUEPM1ZiyM)

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with flex box. Add a 
 class like this

```
<div class="row flexible"></div>
```

Css

```
@media (max-width:480px){
.flexible{
display:flex;
}
.flexible div:nth-child(1){
order:1;
}
.flexible div:nth-child(2){
order:2;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution by adding a class to the col-md-6 and floating it right.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-12 footer-nav">
      <?php
          wp_nav_menu( array(
              'menu'              => 'footer',
              'theme_location'    => 'footer',
              'depth'             => 1,
              'container'         => 'div',
              'container_id'      => 'footer-nav',
              'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
              'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
              'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
          );
      ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 copyright-text">
      <p>Copyright © <?php echo date("Y"); ?> Elliott Davidson. All Rights Reserved.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.footer-nav
  float: right
```