# How to flip columns from bootstrap on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to show a column at the bottom of a page on mobile which is now on top.

I've found this question about it: [How do I change Bootstrap 3 column order on mobile layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171408/how-do-i-change-bootstrap-3-column-order-on-mobile-layout)

But the answer is not working for me.

I got two columns, one col-md-3 and one col-md-9. The md3 contains a search function and product categories while the md9 contains the actual products.

I've tried changing their classes to the following:

col-md-9 col-md-pull-3
col-md-3 col-md-pull-9

But this gives me the following result:

[image]

Why is that?

[This is the website I am working on.](http://studionewmedia.nl/_extern/badenincl/baden)

Comment: Can you give your code ? I have some trouble to understand your problem !

Comment: You can view it in the source code of my link, but I can add it to the question. It's basically a col-md-3 with a col-md-9 beneath it though.

Comment: It's not working because you didn't [switch the order of the columns in the markup](https://www.codeply.com/go/d14lvCuYoe) as shown in the dup.

Comment: @ZimSystem I did now, but I still get the same result.

Comment: Post the code in the question