# Change order of WordPress elements on mobile site

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile

I am creating a website at https://globalstudyukbeta2.000webhostapp.com/

When on a mobile, the flags/country outlines appear directly below the London outline which looks a little odd. I'd love to put them below the 'find out more' button instead.

Current behaviour: Flags - text - button.
Desired behaviour: Text, button, flags.

Thanks! James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your site uses Bootstrap 3, lets use its feature "Pull" and "Push". Bootstrap is "mobile first", so You need to reorder blocks: first "Text", than "Button + Text". The next - use pull and push bootstrap classes to order blocks on desktop.

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171408/how-do-i-change-bootstrap-3-column-order-on-mobile-layout?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) for more details.