# Bootstrap 3 push/pull issue?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i am trying to learn more about push/pull and i am running into some issues. I have 2 divs, how can i make the right div stay at top when screen sizes go medium and below.

This is a [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MNvNRa)

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="main-div">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 lef-div">
        <h4>Number1 : Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
          book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
          with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-xs-12 right-div">
        <h4>Number2 : Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
          book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
          with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for all the help.

Comment: I believe this might be what your looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171408/how-do-i-change-bootstrap-3-column-order-on-mobile-layout

Comment: Are you constrained to BS3? Because BS4 uses `flexbox` and with that, its fairly simple to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: @jakelovelock That article helped me out. Thank you.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Unfortunately yes. i am stuck with BS3. but no worries, it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="main-div">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-lg-push-6">
          <h4>Number2 : Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
              book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
              with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</h4>
          </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-pull-6">
          <h4>Number1 : Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
            book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
            with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

It's always better to keep the order you wanted to keep first on `col-*-12`. It's easier to pull or push on side then pushing it up

Use `col-*-push-*` on the div you wanted to push and use `col-*-pull-*` the dive you wanted to pull on the other side.

Go through this link for reference https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp