# Is there a way to order two divs: image, and text on bootstrap 3 as you are changing the screen resolutions?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I know that on bootstrap 4, you could simply write "order-#" in each div, but my project is based on bootstrap 3 so it would create problems if I change the versions now.

Please note that on a mobile screen, it needs to have this order: Image, Text, Image, Text, Image, text (reading from top to bottom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bootstrap 3, you can use `push` and `pull` as answered here: [How do I change Bootstrap 3 column order on mobile layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171408/how-do-i-change-bootstrap-3-column-order-on-mobile-layout#answer-20171474)

**Edit:**

Here is a simple example that will display:

- **In the 1st row:** Image on the left and Text on the right
- **In the second row:** Text on the left and Image on the right

But on mobile, it will display in this order: Image - Text - Image - Text, because on `md` screen size and up we push the image and we pull the text

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"><img src="my_image.png"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6">Text here</div>
</div>

<div class="row">    
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6"><img src="my_image.png"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-6">Text here</div>
 </div>
```

You can refer to [this documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/) to learn more.

Comment: Could you tell me how I would be able to do that for this specific problem?