# Issue with push/pulling my layout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a simple layout, with a sidebar (col-3) and content (col-9)

```
[3] [9]
```

I'm trying to get it so at xs side my layout is

```
[Content]
[Sidebar]
```

So I tried adding `col-xs-push-12` to the sidebar and `col-xs-pull-12` to the content, however, with that at any size screen everything disappears.

My HTML is set up like

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 col-xs-push-12" id="globalSidebar">
    ...
</div>


<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 col-xs-pull-12" id="mainContent">
       ...
</div>
```

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057270/column-order-manipulation-using-col-lg-push-and-col-lg-pull-in-twitter-bootstrap]) question which is where I got the push/pull from, but it didn't seem to work.

Is this something I can do in just bootstrap or will I need to do something else to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think "mobile-first", and use the push/pull for the larger screen widths, it should work like this..

```
<div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-push-3" id="mainContent">
    content
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-pull-9" id="globalSidebar">
    sidebar
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/uigxL3SGFj)**