# Bootstrap responsive grid changing order of columns when displayed on mobile with rows?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
----------------------
A   |    B     |   C
----------------------
```

when scaled to mobile I will expect:

```
-------
   B
-------
   A
-------
   C
```

Is it possible with new in Bootstrap3 `push` option?

I was trying

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-sm-push-6" style="background-color:red">
        A
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 cols-sm-pull-3 no-col-padding">
    <center>
          B
    </center>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3" style="background-color:pink">
         C
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057270/column-order-manipulation-using-col-lg-push-and-col-lg-pull-in-twitter-bootstrap/18070242#18070242)

- `col-vp-push-x` = push the column to the right by ***x*** number of columns, starting from where the column would normally render -> `position: relative`, on a ***vp*** or larger view-port.
- `col-vp-pull-x` = pull the column to the left by ***x*** number of columns, starting from where the column would normally render -> `position: relative`, on a ***vp*** or larger view-port.

  ***vp*** = xs, sm, md, or lg

  ***x*** = 1 thru 12

I think what messes most people up, **is that you need to change the order of the columns in your HTML markup (in the example below, B comes before A)**, and that it only does the pushing or pulling on view-ports that are greater than or equal to what was specified. i.e. `col-sm-push-5` will only push 5 columns on `sm` view-ports or greater.

- (Desktop) Larger view-ports get pushed and pulled.
- (Mobile) Smaller view-ports render in normal order.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/D2cJS/)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-push-5">
        Content B
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-pull-5">
        Content A
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        Content C
    </div>
</div>
```

**View-port >= sm**

```
|A|B|C|
```

**View-port < sm**

```
|B|
|A|
|C|
```