# Bootstrap pull and push

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm struggling to get my head around the Bootstrap pull and push methods.
I've been playing around and i get a nice working example when switching just 2 divs. I understand that part.

But what i'm trying to achieve needs an extra element.

```
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 " style="background-color:grey;">TEXT</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-12 " style="background-color:lavender;">IMAGE</div>
<div class="col-md-12 col-md-pull-12" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">FORM</div>
</div>
```

I know the example above is wrong, I've deliberately added my form div at 12 cols to push it below the image and text divs, what I want to achieve is:

desktop:

> [  TEXT ]
>   [ IMAGE ]
>
> [........FORM........]

mobile:

> [TEXT ]
>
> [FORM ]
>
> [IMAGE]

From what I can see i need to add something to my text div, I think?

Answer (score 0):

I think if the `col-lg-6` then you can push the column by `col-push-lg-6.`
you can't push the column by double
Use the given example as reference that how it works.

If not enough than see the example given by `DrGeneral` from the given link:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057270/column-order-manipulation-using-col-lg-push-and-col-lg-pull-in-twitter-bootstrap

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-6">
        Text
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12 col-sm-push-12">
        Image
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12 col-sm-pull-12">
        Form
    </div>


</div>
```

Hope this link and examples works.....