# col-push and col-pull bootstrap - how does it work?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been trying to wrap my head around how these work but so far I'm having no luck. On the website I have, the browser version looks like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
     <div class="aside">
          <div class="promo">
               <p>left content</p>    
          </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="content"> 
             <p>right content</p>
        </div>
   </div>
```

For the browser this works great, but on the mobile I'd like it to be layed out like this:

```
       <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="content"> 
                 <p>right content</p>
            </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-4">
         <div class="aside">
              <div class="promo">
                   <p>left content</p>    
              </div>
         </div>
       </div>
```

How would I lay it out with the push and pulls to get it to rearrange properly?

Comment: you can see this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29496846/change-column-order-using-bootstrap-push-and-pull

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to develop with Bootstrap is to think "mobile first". So start with your mobile layout and add push/pull classes for other sizes. Note that I also added in `col-xs-12` to your columns, it's technically not needed but it's nice to be explicit about these.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-push-4">
    <div class="content">
      <p>right content</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-8">
    <div class="aside">
      <div class="promo">
        <p>left content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize you had to change the order around, I will definitely be using this in the future