# Changing column order while stacking them on mobile (bootstrap)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently having two columns like this:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-7'>foo</div>
    <div class='col-sm-5'>blah</div>
</div>
```

I would like them to stack up this way on mobile :
[5] above
[7]
I tried the following :

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-7 col-push-7'>foo</div>
    <div class='col-sm-5 col-pull-5'>blah</div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, it is not working, it still appears as being:
[7] above
[5]
on mobile.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Possible duplication - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057270/column-order-manipulation-using-col-lg-push-and-col-lg-pull-in-twitter-bootstrap

Comment: Are your divs contained within a parent element? If so, what is it?

Comment: It is a row, I just added it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) to reverse the order of the child items, like so:

```css
.row{
    display:flex;
    flex-flow:row wrap-reverse;
    width:100%;
}
.row>div{
    flex:1 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-7">foo</div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">blah</div>
</div>
```

Note that, depending on the browser support you're aiming for, you may need to prefix some of the properties and/or values above. See [canisuse.com's compatibility table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) for more information.