# responsive html newsletter with tables like bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, newsletter

I'd like to send a responsive newsletter. I know how to do it with my style.css

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" width="600" bgcolor="#fff">

 <tbody> 
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-bottom:5px" valign="top">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" width="295" style="background:#ffffff">
                <tbody> 
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding:15px;background-color:#fff">

                        image

                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
       </td>
       <td style="padding-bottom:5px" valign="top">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" width="295" style="background:#ffffff">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding:15px;background-color:#fff">
                        text
                    </td>

                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
       </td>    
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-bottom:5px" valign="top">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" width="295" style="background:#ffffff">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>    
                        <td style="padding:15px;background-color:#fff">
                            text
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>

    </tr>    



 </tbody>
</table>
```

but I have one problem.

In desktop looks great,

```
image                    text
text                     image
```

but in mobile

looks

```
image
text
text
image
```

**and I want it like**

```
image
text
image
text
```

I found [Column order manipulation using col-lg-push and col-lg-pull in Twitter Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057270/column-order-manipulation-using-col-lg-push-and-col-lg-pull-in-twitter-bootstrap) and I was wondering if there is something like that in tables.

I tried to change `align="center"` with `aling="left"` and `align="right"` but nothing.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than getting the side-by-side effect by using two table cells (`td`'s), you need to *make each side a whole table*, and use the `align` property on the table. This lets you have the left or right sides in either order when the email goes to one column.

Julie Ng's Antwort template has a good description + example of this technique:

https://github.com/InterNations/antwort/wiki/Columns-to-Rows-%28Version-1.0%29