# Bootstrap push/pull column issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 4 columns like this

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"> col3</div>
    <div class="col-md-1"> col1</div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> col4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> col4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Normally it looks like this:

[3][1][4][4]

When it's in smaller viewport, I want it to show like this:
[4]
[4]
[3]
[1]

I have tried

```
 <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-push-8"> col3</div>
        <div class="col-md-1 col-md-push-8"> col1</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-4"> col4</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-4"> col4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

It shows: 
In large viewport:
[4][4][3][1]
In viewport that those columns collapse: 
[3]
[1]
[4]
[4]
But it seems like what I did is completely reversed... 
A created a codepen snippet http://codepen.io/ngp130895/pen/Kzxdpj 
How can I achieve this?

Comment: What does it show now?

Comment: after what screen you want to change the design?

Comment: @GauravAggarwal what do you mean by screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may get the solution in this [link](http://www.schmalz.io/2014/10/08/Column-Ordering-in-Bootstrap/)

Comment: also you can get same solution at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057270/column-order-manipulation-using-col-lg-push-and-col-lg-pull-in-twitter-bootstrap

Comment: Bootstrap should definitely edit their documentation. They do not have this mentioned in their doc.

Comment: Yes, but they do not give clear description about that.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for this. <strike>This looks kinda stupid but it works.</strike>

```
 <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-4"> col4</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-4"> col4</div>        
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-8"> col3</div>
        <div class="col-md-1 col-md-pull-8"> col1</div>

      </div>
</div>
```

Edit: I found that this actually the correct way. Mobile view should be written by default and larger viewport is modified by pushing and pulling the columns.

Answer (score -1):

Div is an element `block` and every new div go to the head of the line.
For fix this problem have two way:

> Use tag  
>   Use a code CSS for do became  tag inline

For the first way you must only change tag `<div>`  with `<span`.
For the last way you can use it:

```css
div.container > div.row > div {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"> col3</div>
    <div class="col-md-1"> col1</div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> col4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> col4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand your answer that good. Thanks for answering anyway.