# Inconsistent JavaScript div assignment

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap's grid to organize the layout of a webpage. Between lg and sm sizes, the webpage looks like this:

**|col-1|col-2|**

When the size of the window is in the xs range, the columns stack like this:

**|col-1|**

**|col-2|**

Instead, I want it to stack like this:

**|col-2|**

**|col-1|**

---

To do this, I created a function to switch the inner HTMLs of the div tags. It works some of the time, but occasionally col-1 is still above col-2.

```
function mobileHandler() {
    var width=window.innerWidth;
    if (width<768) {

        var col1=document.getElementById('col1').innerHTML;
        var col2=document.getElementById('col2').innerHTML; 

        document.getElementById('col1').innerHTML=col2;
        document.getElementById('col2').innerHTML=col1;
    } 
}

window.onload=mobileHandler;
window.onresize=mobileHandler;
```

Is there a bug anyone can spot with my code? Or is there a better way to accomplish what I want?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057270/column-order-manipulation-using-col-lg-push-and-col-lg-pull-in-twitter-bootstrap

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Column order manipulation using col-lg-push and col-lg-pull in Twitter Bootstrap 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057270/column-order-manipulation-using-col-lg-push-and-col-lg-pull-in-twitter-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `push` and `pull` features of bootstrap.

See the snippet below.

```css
.cols{
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-md-push-8 cols">
      col-2
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-md-pull-4 cols">
      col-1
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply 'pull-right' to the col-1

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 cols pull-right">
      col-md-4
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 cols">
      col-md-8
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```