# Bootstrap v4 push and pulls

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

So i have read this topic: [Column order manipulation using col-lg-push and col-lg-pull in Twitter Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057270/column-order-manipulation-using-col-lg-push-and-col-lg-pull-in-twitter-bootstrap)

But i still have some problems:

[image]

My code ( i have shortened it a bit, but i think nothing important is missing):

```
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...
        </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-10 justify-content-center"  >
        /*My login div*/
    </div>
```

So, what i want to happen: on small screens i want my `Login div` be almost as wide as a screen (10/12 and centered), PLUS i want it float on the top of the screen, before the text. I assume i have to add something like `pull-sm-12` to my `Login div` and something like `push-sm-10` to my `Text div`, but it doesn't work, my div just float beyond screen borders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 has moved to a full flexbox model, so the push/pull utilities are no more. They are replaced by the ["order" utilities](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/#order). (Hint: The documentation seems to be out of date. Even though the class names start with `order` in the documentation, they actually start with `flex`, i.e. `flex-first`, not `order-first`.) Anyways, based on what you described, I think the following code will get you mostly there.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="d-flex flex-sm-wrap flex-md-nowrap justify-content-sm-center justify-content-md-start">
    <div class="flex-sm-last flex-md-unordered">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...
    </div>
    <div class="flex-sm-first flex-md-unordered"  >
        Login box
    </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, the Stack Overflow snippet functionality doesn't really let you play with responsiveness. It's all defined widths, apparently. You should copy the code somewhere else to play around with it.