# change col position in html

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i have this code

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        Content B
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <img src="https://www.ipbrick.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/cloud.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="col-sm-5">
          Content A
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
          Content C
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and it's displayed

> desktop
>
> ----b----|--d--|--a--|----c----
>
> mobile
>
> b
>
> d
>
> a
>
> c

i want in mobile mode displaying

> d
>
> b
>
> a
>
> c

I have been read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057270/column-order-manipulation-using-col-lg-push-and-col-lg-pull-in-twitter-bootstrap) article, but i still cannot understand, maybe someone can explain to me?

Comment: you can try this link here...

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#flex-order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code, i used flex to make it work. don't forget to put the code inside the media query `@media all and (max-width:767px)` or whatever you want

```css
.col-row{
display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    /* optional */
    -webkit-box-align: start;
    -moz-box-align: start;
    -ms-flex-align: start;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    }
    /* use the below code under mobile media query */
     .col-b {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -ms-flex-order: 2;
    -webkit-order: 2;
    order: 2;
  }
.col-row img{
width: 30px;
}
.col-xs-12 {
    text-align: center;
}
  .col-row {
    align-items: center;
}
  .col-d {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -ms-flex-order: 1;
    -webkit-order: 1;
    order: 1;
  }
  @media all and (max-width:320px){
  .col-row {
    align-items: center;
}

  }
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-row">
    <div class="col-sm-7 col-b">
        Content B
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-d">
        <img src="https://www.ipbrick.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/cloud.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="col-sm-5">
          Content A
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
          Content C
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: your code is work but, when i using screen 320px i want images position in center, is it possible?

Comment: @BayuRizkiIsnaeniHidayatuloh wich images? you didn't mentioned any images in the code, if you want to make it centre, make sure the images doesn't have float:left or right, it should be display:inline-block , and add `text-align:center` to its parent.

Comment: sorry i forgot to set image in content D, the problem is in .col-row {display: flex} when i set {display: block} image position center but the sequence does not match

Comment: No need to put the div `display:block`, just set the content D to text align center

Comment: @BayuRizkiIsnaeniHidayatuloh check now, i added `justify-content:center`

Answer (score 0):

If you can swap around the B and D columns in the HTML and then use the bootstrap css classes to push and pull the columns to they are arranged differently on desktop and then go back to their 'normal' order on mobile:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-push-7">
                Content d
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-7 col-sm-pull-5">
                Content B
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                Content A
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                Content C
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```