# Change div order on mobile screens for expanding div

Tags: html, css

I have 4 divs, each contain a link which opens a new different div below all 4 (it's a section about services), for mobile screens (669px and below) I need the div which the link opens to display underneath the div containing the link instead of below all 4 divs.

I've tried some of the answers on here already such as

```
function resize(){
if($(window).width() < 670){
$("#service1").insertAfter("#service-box1");
}
}
```

but I'm sure I'll be doing something wrong when putting it in my code

Here's the simplified html for the divs

```
<div id="services-container" class="row">


 <div class="service" id="service-box1">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <a class="learn-more" id="show1" data-href="service1">Learn More</a>
 </div>
 <div class="service" id="service-box2">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <a class="learn-more" id="show2" data-href="service2">Learn More</a>
 </div>
 <div class="service" id="service-box3">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <a class="learn-more" id="show3" data-href="service3">Learn More</a>
 </div>
 <div class="service" id="service-box4">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <a class="learn-more" id="show4" data-href="service4">Learn More</a>
 </div>


 <div class="service-content" id="service1">
  <h1>Service1</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="service-content" id="service2">
  <h1>Service2</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="service-content" id="service3">
  <h1>Service3</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="service-content" id="service4">
  <h1>Service4</h1>
 </div>


</div>
```

Here's the function to open the service-content div for the first div

```
$('document').ready(function() {
$('#show1').click( function() {
var $div = $('#' + $(this).data('href'));
$('.service-content').not($div).hide();
$div.slideToggle();
});
});
```

That code opens the service-content divs below all 4 of the service divs. On mobile screens I need service1 to display under service-box1 and above service-box2 and so-on. I don't know whether this means reworking the whole code or if there's a function to do it, any help is appreciated.

Comment: That is something you should be doing with CSS and media queries, not JavaScript and jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can easily achieve this using `CSS` with `flexbox` or `grids`. A sample using `flexbox` is created by me over https://jsfiddle.net/saksham_malhotra/tjom0Le1/

The main concept here is to use media queries as

```
@media (max-width:600px) { 
    /*Your logic here*/
}
```

Just try to resize the window in the sample an see the layout change.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to archieve this problem is to see how others do it. [HERE IS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057270/column-order-manipulation-using-col-lg-push-and-col-lg-pull-in-twitter-bootstrap) logic used in bootstrap 3 (and 4). You can look at bootstrap library code or just use it.